# React router memoized route wizard

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a wizard component that is built around a class holding the questions in an array and passing the current question to a `Wizard` component.
I wish for each question to have a corresponding route.
The question object inside the array:

```
            [{
                route: 'service-option',
                getComponent: props => {
                    return <QuestionOne {...props}/>;
                },
                ...
            },
            ...
            ]
```

I'm trying to render a memoized react `Route` component based on the `question` prop passed to the `Wizard` like so:

```
    const memoizedQuestionRoute = useMemo(() => {
        history.push(`wizard/${question.route}`);
        const component = React.cloneElement(question.getComponent(...), {...});
        return <Route path={`wizard/${question.route}`} render={props => component}/>;
    }, [question]);
```

and render it in a `div` like so:

```
<div>
    {memoizedQuestionRoute}
</div>
```

Problem is that the route is not even rendering and I don't see it inside the div. Any ideas why and how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

if you haven't decided yet. Get this in component.

```
import { __RouterContext as RouterContext } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useContext } from 'react';

/**
 * useRouter hook for react-router
 */
const useRouter = () => useContext(RouterContext);

export default useRouter;
```